# When does the 'system start' occur if Task Scheduler with the /sc onstart parameter is used?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, task-scheduler

When does the 'system start' occur if Task Scheduler with the /sc onstart parameter is used?

I.e. where would the 'system start' entry be on the following list:

1. Windows boots up, loads the drivers
2. Windows logon screen shows up
3. Windows launches some crucial services / applications

As I know little about the Windows boot process, I'd be pleased if the answer contained a brief description of /reference to the Windows boot process/sequence.

This question is closely related to the second question I posted: [SO question](https://superuser.com/questions/397459/why-task-scheduler-fails-to-open-a-gui-application-window-when-sc-onstart-param)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServiceGroupOrder
```

This controls in which order your services are started.

For me, near the end, there is the `SchedulerGroup`.
So when Windows starts, it will start all services in that given order (before a user can even log in).

The scheduler will start the *System Start* jobs as soon as it is initialized.